# WPF EF 6.0 "No connection string named 'xyz' could be found in the configuration file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration

I am getting an InvalidOperation Exception from EF saying "No connection string named 'xyz' could be found in the configuration file. However, I used the EF wizard to create the model using Database First.  It connected fine (at design time) and created all the EDMX stuff in the folder I named EF.

Caveat: Our project runs as a plug in to another program, it requires us to put this statement into the Build Output Path ......\Bin\, we put all build content 4 directories behind the directory of the project.

I've tried manually copying the app.config to one directory behind the Bin directory shown above.  I've put it in the Bin directory above and cannot get project to find the configuration file.

Any hints?

Comment: Rather than trying to manually copy are you adding another app config in Visual Studio?  I could make a project that is a class library that contains my code and it has EF 6.0.  Then I create a console app, wpf app, asp.net whatever and it will fail.  Why?  It ALSO needs the app config to reference the connection as well as having the EF assemblies to consume it.  Generally I would use NuGet to manage the libraries that have EF and ensure the connection strings are as needed.  Code first needs a connection string as does database first.

Comment: the config file must be in the form [applicationname].exe.config. For example, if the main application is called YouShouldReadCLRViaCSharp.exe, the config file should be named YouShouldReadCLRViaCSharp.exe.config and it should reside in the same directory as YouShouldReadCLRViaCSharp.exe.

Comment: how do you mean plug-in into another program? If yuo do so, the program should have any interface to load your plugin's configuration.

Comment: The project is a plug-in for another application currently installed on the computer doing the debug. That application knows the folder locations to scan for the plug in.  It's that application which starts up and then calls the project I'm working on to load.

Comment: Will, the project I'm working on does copy the Myproject.dll.config to the bin directory.  If I open the file, the connecting strings are there.

Comment: @JohnPeters try manually adding the relevant tags to the config of the master program. Only one config is read automatically and thats the one of the executing assembly. It doesn't matter if you also copy `myproject.dll.config` if there is `executingassembly.exe.config` being used.

Comment: also manually reading your `myproject.dll.config` could be a solution, however I've never tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a97c96dc-696e-420c-bb89-0dafc236780b/manually-read-appconfig-from-separate-dll?forum=netfxbcl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this problem was that the debug version of this program was not running in the typical debug folder root/bin/debug.  Our team had put code into the project file to copy and execute the content in the programs(x86) folder where the plug in had to be in order for the host solution to find it.

If this happens to you, this code will tell you where the assembly is executing:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.
```

Once I put that in as a debug statement, I knew where to look for the configuration file.

I missed this initially because the copy statements in the project file are not readily visible in the Build/Post Build areas.  You have to open the project file to see them.

Answer (score 1):

To use Entity Framework, your executing assembly needs to find information about EF in its config file. In a WPF application, this is usually `App.config` which gets renamed into `Projectname.exe.config` however when debugging, `Projectname.vshost.exe.config` is used, which you should check.

The config file needs to contain three important things in order to run Entity Framework.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections> <!-- 1.  a section "entityFramework" -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>


    <connectionStrings> <!-- 2. a connection string -->
        <add name="YourContext" connectionString="todo" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <entityFramework> <!-- 3. entityFramework Tag -->
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

All of these sections are generated when using the Wizard. You just need to copy them into the right config file.

**EDIT** Just to point out some other basics

*Only one* `Config-File` is opened at Application-Startup. That is `<NameOfApp>.exe.config`.

Upon building your application - *building the executeable Project*, `App.config` contained inside will be copied to the output direcotory and renamed, as described above. In any scenario where some other Assembly is used, e.g. a library-project or whatever, *if* there is relevant data contained inside the app.config of the library-project, it will simply not be used automatically. 
This is why you will have to perform the above steps.

In **OP's Case**, his program `MyProgram.dll` will be copied into another directory, where another program (lets call it `Master.exe`) will execute this assembly. This means, even if he had also copied `MyProgram.dll.config` it would not be opened automatically, because the running config in this case is `Master.exe.config`. If OP wants some configuration to be used, he either needs to copy it into `Master.exe.config` which is not very clean, as I expect this to be a whole other Project and thus, they should really be seperated. *So* he'd need to manually perform some code, running the configurations of his Plug-Ins.

Comment: Thanks for response Lucky, I used EF DB First connection wizard so all of what you show above is in the app.config file (root folder). I've tried to set the App.Config as Content, Copy Always and Embedded resource, none will work.

Comment: I can get the connection to work if I manually code the full connection string as a parameter to this call:   using (var db = new FilterConnection(connectionString)) where connection string is the entire app.config data created by EF Wizard.  This tells me the connection string is correct!  Why wouldn't the applicaiton be able to read the app.config file?

Comment: As you said, your program is running as a plug-in into another program. First try running your Project in another solution, using console application or Unit-Tests. - *As this should work anyway, just test if you can read an entity*. If this works, it must be on how the Plug-In mechanics work. At this point, no one can really help you, with the information you provided about this system. All I can say is: `whereever your program is searching for the connectionstring, it doesn't find it.` Try sticking to that.